# How do I filter multiple rows with matching column values based on all rows meeting a certain condition? [R]

Tags: r

I have a data table called `iso`:

```
> iso
                     variant_id             transcript_id is_NL counts nrows
     1: chr10_129450960_T_C_b38 chr10_129467297_129536240     0  33029   458
     2: chr10_129450960_T_C_b38 chr10_129467297_129536240     1   3477    54
     3: chr10_129450960_T_C_b38 chr10_129467297_129536240     2    130     3
     4: chr10_129450960_T_C_b38 chr10_129536378_129563778     0     51   458
     5: chr10_129450960_T_C_b38 chr10_129536378_129563778     1      8    54
    ---
500148:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649082_34649409     1   4214    57
500149:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649082_34649409     2    171     2
500150:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649565_34650368     0  48713   456
500151:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649565_34650368     1   4932    57
500152:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649565_34650368     2    208     2
```

I filtered it such that for each row, when `is_NL == 0`, only include the row if `counts/nrows < 50` **or** when `is_NL == c(1, 2)`, only include the row if `counts/nrows < 50`:

```
> iso[with(iso, (is_NL == 0 & counts/nrows < 50) |
+                 (is_NL %in% c(1,2) & counts/nrows > 50)),]
                     variant_id             transcript_id is_NL counts nrows
     1: chr10_129450960_T_C_b38 chr10_129467297_129536240     1   3477    54
     2: chr10_129450960_T_C_b38 chr10_129536378_129563778     0     51   458
     3: chr10_129450960_T_C_b38 chr10_129536378_129707894     1   3847    54
     4: chr10_129450960_T_C_b38 chr10_129701913_129707894     0    188   458
     5: chr10_129450960_T_C_b38 chr10_129708044_129715519     0     17   458
    ---
198076:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34648908_34648997     0    611   456
198077:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649082_34649409     1   4214    57
198078:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649082_34649409     2    171     2
198079:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649565_34650368     1   4932    57
198080:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649565_34650368     2    208     2
```

However, now I realized that I only want to include rows whose other instances of matching `variant_id` and `transcript_id` meet that criteria. For example:

```
500150:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649565_34650368     0  48713   456
500151:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649565_34650368     1   4932    57
500152:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649565_34650368     2    208     2
```

The above demonstrates what I mean. The `variant_id` and `transcript_id` pairs, for each value of `is_NL`, meets the criteria of either `counts/nrows < 50` (when `is_NL == 0`) or `counts/nrows > 50` (when `is_NL == c(1, 2)`)

```
198077:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649082_34649409     1   4214    57
198078:   chr9_34699703_G_C_b38    chr9_34649082_34649409     2    171     2
```

The above is an example of what I do not want. Both rows have matching `variant_id` and `transcript_id` values and the correct value for `counts/nrows`, but the row containing `is_NL == 0` is missing presumably because, for that row, `counts/nrows !< 50`.

I hope I have made myself clear. I just want instances where `variant_id` and `transcript_id` match, and `counts/nrows` for each value of `is_NL` is either < 50 if `is_NL == 0` and > 50 if `is_NL == c(1,2)`.

If this is done correctly, I should have triplets of `variant_id` and `transcript_id` combinations, and each triplet should have an `is_NL` value of either 0, 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```r
library(dplyr)

iso <- setDT(iso)[with(iso, (is_NL == 0 & counts/nrows < 50) | (is_NL %in% c(1,2) & counts/nrows > 50)),][, triplet := .N, by = .(variant_id, transcript_id)][triplet == 3, ][, triplet := NULL]
```

It creates a temporary variable and selects only those rows which create needed triplets.

Comment: Hmm.. it's not giving me the desired result. Should I try that line after `iso[with(iso, (is_NL == 0 & counts/nrows < 50) | (is_NL %in% c(1,2) & counts/nrows > 50)),]`?

Comment: Yes, I did not wanted to change anything of your concept, just add something.

Comment: The answer has now been edited and should work as is.